# Import components for server-side rendering in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've got a nice little ES6 React component file (simplified for this explanation). It uses a library that is browser-specific, [store](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js)  This all works beautifully on the browser:

```js
/app/components/HelloWorld.js:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import store from 'store';

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.set('my-local-data', 'foo-bar-baz');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hello-world">Hello World</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to get it to render on the server as follows, using [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/):

```js
/server/routes/hello-world.js:

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import HelloWorld from '../../app/components/HelloWorld'

export default function(req, res) {
  res.render('root', {
    reactHTML: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<HelloWorld />),
  });
}
```

I get an error from the node server saying "window is not defined" due to importing 'store'.  Ideally I could conditionally import by detecting the environment (node vs browser), but conditional imports aren't supported in ES6.

What's best way to get around this?  I don't actually need to execute the browser code (in this case `componentDidMount` won't be called by `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`) just get it running from node.

Comment: The thing, that you are doing will cause a lot of issues. As far as I found, the store.js is a library to save data into localStorage. By design, localStorage is a browser thing, so you can't get access to user's localStorage from the server. If have server-side render of components relied on the `store`, you should review your architecture.

Comment: No, see my last line about not wanting to call this code but only get it compiling.  ReactDOMServer will never execute the store logic as it only calls `render()`

Comment: ok, got it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be using [babel-rewire-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-rewire-plugin). You can add it to babel-register via the `plugins` option

```
require('babel/register')({
  plugins: ['babel-rewire-plugin']
});
```

Then rewire your `store` dependency to a mocked store:

```
HelloWorld.__Rewire__('store', {
  set: () => {} // no-op
});
```

You can now render HelloWorld from the server peacefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress the load of some npm module, you can just mock it.

Put this on your node.js application setup, before the `HelloWorld.js` import:

```
require.cache[require.resolve('store')] = {
  exports: {
    set() {} // no-op
  }
};
```

This value will be used instead of the real module, which doesn't need on your purposes. Node.js module API is stable, so this behavior will not be broken and you can rely on it.